# Do I have to migrate rows of Coredata base?

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data, core-data-migration

I have an app on the store, with populated data in a CoreData base. For pre-populating the database, we generated a .sqlite file with the application data.

For example in the table PERSON, I have

```
134  Martin  Developer
256  John    Boss
371  Doe     Somebody
```

In the new version of my app, the PERSON table looks like

```
134  Martin  Developer
256  John    Boss
399  Mister  Someoneelse
```

So I replaced the 371 line by the 399 one.

It works fine, except when I install the new app over the old one. In this case, data don't change at all. I looks like a migration problem, but the database structure is exactly the same. Only rows have changed.

Is it a migration problem ?

Comment: If the model is the same as before, no migration is involved...it's a simple an update..maybe you could try to post the code you are using to update the person...

Comment: How do you work with tables and rows in Core Data? Thats not the level of how you should see Core Data Store, really.

Comment: @Flex_Addicted: I work on a very huge application (not mine), and unfortunately I can't show you 3 or 4 lines of code which would say "something"...

Comment: @Nikita: The app data is pre-populated. We generate a .sqllite file which contains our products, for example

Comment: Have you deleted the app and reinstalled again? Maybe this could be the problem...

Comment: Yes, this IS the problem: I cannot ask my users to delete their app before updating the new one!

Comment: Where did you put that store? Within the bundle?

Comment: Yes, it's a sqlite file that I include in my application Bundle.

Comment: You cannot change anything in your bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a prepopulated database, you typically **copy it** to the application document directory the first time it is run on a device. Presumably, you want to save user data in the database as well and the sqlite store has to be in the application document directory to be writable.

So, if you did not do the copying - implement this first.

Then (assuming you did not change your data model), to do the change in your question,

1. retrieve the record in question
2. delete it
3. insert the replacement
4. save

Comment: Yes, you're right. I never noticed that the sqlite file is first copied in my document directory (I'm not the first developer of the app). I understand better now, why the data can be edited.